# Mockito returnsFirstArg() to use

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

I've started using the Mockito `AdditionalAnswers#returnsFirstArg`, which is great:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString())).then(returnsFirstArg());
```

but I was wondering if there is an easy way to extract the input argument in order to be used for example in a constructor like:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString())).thenReturn(new MyObject((String)returnsFirstArg()));
```

(which obviously doesn't work...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest (only?) approach, IMHO, would be to use the `thenAnswer` method, which allows you to not only return a value, but actually execute some code. Java 8 makes this particularly elegant, as you could just use an anonymous lambda:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString()))
    .thenAnswer(i -> new MyObject((String)i.getArguments()[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you maybe need a helper class `AnswerPipeline` that I will introduce it a moment how to make the test more **readable**, more **expressiveness** and more **interesting**!!!

*Note*: you can transform any `Answer` to `AnswerPipeline` by `AnswerPipeline#will(Answer)` method, not only `returnsFirstArg()`.

**THEN** using syntax sugar to describe the test, for example:

```
Function<String, String> function = mock(Function.class);

when(function.apply(anyString())).then(
    /**/ will(returnsFirstArg()) // adapt an Answer to an AnswerPipeline
    /**/.as(String.class)  // set the result type
    /**/.to(String::toUpperCase) // transforming the result
);

assertThat(function.apply("first"), equalTo("FIRST"));
```

**AND** then it is easy to solving your problem with no difficulty:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString()))
           .then(will(returnsFirstArg()).as(String.class).to(MyObject::new));
```

### AnswerPipeline class

```
interface AnswerPipeline<T> extends Answer<T> {

    static <R> AnswerPipeline<R> will(Answer<R> answer) {
        return answer::answer;
    }

    default <R> AnswerPipeline<R> as(Class<R> type) {
        return to(type::cast);
    }

    default <R> AnswerPipeline<R> to(Function<T, R> mapper) {
        return it -> mapper.apply(answer(it));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Fits very well with the fluent style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `thenAnswer` method and create an `Answer` to get the argument:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public MyObject answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        String s = invocation.getArgument(0); // get first argument
        return new MyObject(s);
    }
});
```

If you're using java 8, you can use lambda syntax:

```
when(myMock.myFunction(anyString()))
  .thenAnswer(args -> new MyObject(args.getArgument(0)));
```

**Notes**:

- I didn't need to cast `invocation.getArgument(0)` to `String`, but depending on your java/mockito version, maybe it'll be necessary: `(String) invocation.getArgument(0)`
- depending on your mockito version, the `getArgument(int)` method might not exist and you should use `getArgumentAt(int, Class)` instead (in this case, the call would be `getArgumentAt(0, String.class)`). Or you can use `getArguments()[0]` and cast it to `String`