# default Stream<E> stream() vs static<T> Stream<T> of(T t)

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

`default Stream<E> stream()` is added to `Collection` interface to support streams in Java 8. Similar functionality is supported by `public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t)` in `Stream` class. What different purpose is static of() method solving ?

Comment: You can create a Stream using varargs and arrays, not possible directly via the Collection-way.

Answer (score 6):

The method `stream()` of the `Collection` interface can be called on an *existing* collection. Being an interface method, it can be overridden by actual collection implementations to return a `Stream` adapted to the specific collection type.

The standard collections of the JRE don’t take this opportunity, as the default implementation’s strategy of delegating to `spliterator()`, which is also an overridable method, suits their needs. But the documentation even mentions scenarios in which the collection *should* override [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--):

> This method should be overridden when the [spliterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#spliterator--) method cannot return a spliterator that is `IMMUTABLE`, `CONCURRENT`, or *late-binding*.

---

In contrast, the `static` factory method(s) `Stream.of(…)` are designed for the case when you have a fixed number of elements *without* a specific collection. There is no need to create a temporary `Collection` when all you want is a single `Stream` over the elements you can enumerate.

Without collections of potentially different type, there is no need for overridable behavior, hence, a `static` factory method is sufficient.

---

Note that even if you don’t have a enumerable fixed number of elements, there is an optimized solution for the task of creating a single stream, when no reusable collection is needed:

```
Stream.Builder<MyType> builder=Stream.builder();
builder.add(A);
if(condition) builder.add(B);
builder.add(C);
builder.build()./* stream operations */
```

Comment: first, up-vote. but the primary different between `Collection.stream`  & `Stream.of` is, the first is applying Template Method Pattern but the second applying Factory Method Pattern. and they are both factory methods. am I right?

Comment: `Collection.stream` may also be considered to fulfill the *abstract factory* pattern (even if there is a default). It’s not unusual to identify more than one pattern in a software. You may confine it by using the term *static factory method* as the name of the pattern behind the `Stream.of` method. I even happened to do that in my answer unconsciously. I usually prefer focusing on the implications of a design rather than the names of the software design pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I think your comment is a great answer than any answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, `of` is just an utility method to create Streams on the fly, without the need to wrap your elements inside a collection first.

*Generally* static factory methods as `of` are provided to skip the array creation because of var-args. For example java-9 immutable collections provide *many* overloads of these methods like:

```
 Set.of()
 Set.of(E)
 Set.of(E e1, E e2)
 .... so on until 11
 Set.of(E... elem)
```

Even the description of those methods is:

> While this introduces some clutter in the API, it avoids array allocation, initialization, and garbage collection overhead that is incurred by varargs calls

Since there are *only* two methods in Stream:

```
 Stream.of(T t)
 Streamm.of(T ... values)
```

I consider that small utility methods that can create Streams from `var-args`.

But they still provide a method that creates a Stream with a single element (instead of leaving *just* the var-args method), so for a single element this is already optimized.

Comment: The reason why there are not so many `Stream.of` methods like `Set.of` or `List.of`, is that the latter guaranty to return an immutable collection, hence, can’t just keep a reference to the array which might be shared. In contrast, `Stream.of(T...)` just delegates to the `Arrays.stream`, so the resulting stream will iterate over the array without another copying step.

Answer (score 2):

A interface can add static methods/default methods since jdk-8. and you can see some examples of applying patterns on interface in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661433/java-default-interface-methods-concrete-use-cases).

**First**, they are both calling `StreamSupport.stream` to create a stream.

```
// Collection.stream()
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}

// Stream.of(E)
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Streams.StreamBuilderImpl<>(t), false);
}
```

stream() added to Collection interface is a good example to applying [Template-Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in interface by default methods. and you can see the source code that stream method call a method `spliterator` which implements by default in Collection interface.

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}

default Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliterator(this, 0);
}
```

**AND** class derived from `Collection` can be override `spliterator` implements different algorithm that will using highest performance algorithm instead. for example `spliterator` in `ArrayList`:

```
public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return new ArrayListSpliterator<>(this, 0, -1, 0);
}
```

**Finally**, Stream.of() method is a good example to applying [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in interface by static method. it's a factory method for create a stream from an object instance.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers clearly explain the differences between `Collection.stream` and `Stream.of`, when to use one or the other, which design patterns are being applied, etc. @Holger goes even further and shows a sample usage of `Stream.Builder`, which I think is highly under-used.

Here I want to complement the other answers by showing a mixed usage of both `Stream.of` and `Collection.stream` methods. I hope that this example would be clear enough to show that even if both `Stream.of` and `Collection.stream` are completely different methods, they can also be used together to fulfil a more complex requirement.

Suppose you have `N` lists, all of them containing elements of the same type:

```
List<A> list1 = ...;
List<A> list2 = ...;
...
List<A> listN = ...;
```

And you want to create one stream with the elements of all lists.

You could create a new empty list and add the elements of all the lists into this new list:

```
int newListSize = list1.size() + list2.size() + ... + listN.size();
List<A> newList = new ArrayList<>(newListSize);

newList.addAll(list1);
newList.addAll(list2);
...
newList.addAll(listN);
```

Then, you could call `stream()` on this list and you would be done:

```
Stream<A> stream = newList.stream();
```

However, you would be creating an intermediate, pointless list, with the sole purpose of streaming the elements of the original `list1`, `list2`, ..., `listN` lists.

A much better approach is to use `Stream.of`:

```
Stream<A> stream = Stream.of(list1, list2, ..., listN)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

This first creates a stream of lists by enumerating each one of them and then flat-maps this stream of lists into a stream of all lists' elements by means of the `Stream.flatMap` operation. Thus, `Collection.stream` is called when flat-mapping the original stream.

Comment: first, up-vote. a good practice for combine Collection streams. but you can also using `Stream.concat(...streams)`.

Comment: after thinking. I think your way is pretty way do that. good jobs. and writing a composing method is unnecessary. and duplicate logic with `Stream.of(...Collection).flatMap(Collection::stream)`